# transform.localPosition vs trans.localPosition(cache)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

which one have better performance ? or is it same ? because i saw in an article which told me to cache the component instead of `getComponent` every frame.

which is better performance

```
void Update(){
    transform.localPosition
}
```

### OR

```
Transform trans;

void Awake(){
    trans = GetComponent<Transform>();
}

void Update(){
    trans.localPosition;
}
```

Comment: Can you select my response (check-mark) as the answer if it helped please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you read on your article is true: saving a reference to a component would be more performance-helpful than using `GetComponent()` in every frame.

However, Unity stores a default reference to the transform of the object on which your monobehavior script is attached. When you use `transform.localPosition` (same as `this.transform.localPosition`), you're using that default reference (which is more similar to your idea of caching your component than GetComponent()).

To answer your question:
Both your code approaches you provided would perform almost exactly the same, except that the first approach skips an extra reference assignment (assuming you call `trans = this.transform` somewhere in the code in your second approach).

I hope that helps!